# PhpStorm 7.1.3: How to add an expression to the Watch pane?

Tags: php, debugging, expression, phpstorm, watch

According to the docs it should be possible to add an expression to the watch pane in PhpStorm 7.1.3:

> **To add an item to a watch**
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> - In the Watches pane, click add, or just press Insert.
> - **On the Variables pane, in the Inspection window, or in the Evaluate Expression dialog box, right-click the desired item and choose Add to Watches on the context menu.**
> - Select the desired item in the Variables pane and drag it to the Watches pane.
> - Select item in the editor, right-click it and select Add to Watches on the context menu.

([Source](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/adding-editing-and-removing-watches.html))

However, the context menu in the [Expression Editor](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/evaluating-expressions.html) doesn't offer the option to add the expression to the watch pane:

[image]

It doesn't even work with "normal" variables.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: PhpStorm version used?

Comment: PhpStorm 7.1.3 - I'll update the question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this option was added in v8 (currently Public Preview stage).

You can get latest v8 build and check it: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/08/phpstorm-8-public-preview/